# Can't run Dart 2 command line programs

Tags: dart

I am trying to write a simple command line program with Dart 2. I have used Dart 2 before with Flutter without any problems, but when trying to run my command line application, I can't get it to work.
I am getting the following error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: Attempted to use type '_Testtt' as a function. Since types do not define a method 'call', this is not possible. Did you intend to call the _Testtt constructor and forget the 'new' operator?
Receiver: _Testtt
```

I am confident that nothing is wrong with my class. Also, in VS Code, it recognizes that it is in fact a constructor.
I am using the Dart version that ships with Flutter.

Does any one have an idea?

Dart Version:

```
Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.59.0.flutter-ff815d05a5 (Tue May 29 20:01:09 2018 +0000) on "windows_x64"
```

pubspec:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.55.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  http: "^0.11.3+16"

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^0.12.30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the modified flutter SDK for normal Dart programs. Download the regular SDK (albeit the [dev channel](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk/archive) - currently 2.0.0-dev.60.0) and install it somewhere away from your flutter installation. Use this SDK for non-Flutter Dart programs.

There's a command line argument that you need to turn on to get the regular Dart SDK to support the new 2.0 features like optional `new`. When running from the command line specify `--preview-dart-2`.